# I'd like some help to write sql code to return a list of customer data items ranked by frequency (high to low)

Tags: sql, report

The table I am querying has several thousand rows and numerous fields - I'd like the code to return the top 10 values for a handful of the fields, namely: Forename, Surname and City - I'd also like to see a count of the values returned.

For example

| Ranking | Forename | FName Frequency | Surname | SName Frequency | City | City Frequency |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Liam | 830,091 | Smith | 2,353,709 | New York | 2,679,785 |
| 2 | Mary | 708,390 | Johnson | 1,562,990 | Los Angeles | 413,359 |
| 3 | Noah | 639,592 | Williams | 792,306 | Chicago | 393,511 |
| 4 | Patricia | 568,410 | Brown | 743,346 | Houston | 367,496 |
| 5 | William | 557,049 | Jones | 633,933 | Phoenix | 336,929 |
| 6 | Linda | 497,138 | Miller | 503,523 | Philadelphia | 304,638 |
| 7 | James | 490,665 | Davis | 503,115 | San Antonio | 255,142 |
| 8 | Barbara | 418,312 | Garcia | 468,683 | San Diego | 238,521 |
| 9 | Logan | 399,947 | Rodriguez | 461,816 | Dallas | 232,718 |
| 10 | Elizabeth | 399,737 | Wilson | 436,843 | San Jose | 213,483 |

The returned list should be interpreted thus:
The most frequently occurring forename in the table is Liam - with 830,091 instances,
The 5th most frequently occurring forename is William - with 557,049 instances,
The 8th most frequently occurring city is San Diego - with  238,521 instances
...and so on

(N.b. the table does not show there are 2.7m Liams in New York - just that there are 830,091 Liams in the entire table - and that there are 2,679,785 New York addresses in the entire table)

The following produces what I need - but just for the first field (Forename) - I'd like to be able to do the same for three fields

```
SELECT Forename, COUNT(Forename) AS FName_Frequency
FROM Customer_Table
GROUP BY Forename
ORDER BY FName_Frequency DESC
limit 10
```

Thanks in anticipation

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would just put this in separate rows:

```
select 'forename', forename, count(*) as freq
from customer_table
group by forename
order by freq desc
fetch first 10 rows only
union all
select 'surname', surname, count(*) as freq
from customer_table
group by surname
order by freq desc
fetch first 10 rows only
union all
select 'city', city, count(*) as freq
from customer_table
group by city
order by freq desc
fetch first 10 rows only;
```

Note that this uses Standard SQL syntax, because you have not tagged with the question with the database you are using.  You can also put this in separate columns, using:

```
select max(case when which = 'forename' then col end),
       max(case when which = 'forename' then freq end),
       max(case when which = 'surname' then col end),
       max(case when which = 'surname' then freq end),
       max(case when which = 'city' then col end),
       max(case when which = 'city' then freq end)
from ((select 'forename' as which, forename as col, count(*) as freq,
              row_number() over (order by count(*) desc) as seqnum
       from customer_table
       group by forename
      ) union all
      (select 'surname' as which, surname, count(*) as freq
              row_number() over (order by count(*) desc) as seqnum
       from customer_table
       group by surname
      ) union all
      (select 'city', city, count(*) as freq,
              row_number() over (order by count(*) desc) as seqnum
       from customer_table
       group by city
      )
     ) x
group by seqnum;
```